# How to increase the thread count of running cppcheck process in linux

Tags: linux, cppcheck

I trying  to increase the thread count of running cppcheck process by using following command

cppcheck -j9 --enable=warning,style,performance,portability,information,missingInclude

but still only one thread is running in background.

Can anyone help me to get the solution.

Answer (score 2):

hi I am a Cppcheck developer. That should work.

However, each source file is checked by 1 thread. If you only check 1 source file then -j9 has no effect. If you check 2 files then both -j2 and -j9 has the effect that 2 threads are used.